# In Rails ActiveRecord, how can you create a scope that uses a join through another model (two inner joins)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a system with instructors, services offered, and availabilities.

An instructor can offer one or more servies, and an availability is associated with an instructor.

I  want to create a scope on availabilities that gets all availabilities of a service.

The classes:

```
class Instructor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :instructor_availabilities

  has_and_belongs_to_many :services
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_and_belongs_to_many :instructors
end

class InstructorAvailabililty < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :instructor
  attr_accessible time

  scope :of_service, lambda { |service_id| 
    #code goes here for this scope
  }
end
```

How would I implement this of_service scope, using two inner joins to get availabilities of a service (by going through the instructors to services mapping)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
class Scheduling::InstructorAvailability < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :instructor
  attr_accessible time

  joins(:instructor => :services).where('scheduling_instructors_services.service_id' => service_id)   
  }
end
```